# Nested if loop not working in python when renaming file

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to change the file name inside my folder. My file name is "20.1.tif". I want to rename this in "20.1". The second number *.1.* goes till 7 like 20.7 and the first number is till 280.
i tried looping through the files and renaming it but its not looping through the first number.
It goes "20.8".And as there is no 20.8 it through file not found error

```
 import os
    a = 20
    b = 1
    while True:
        old_file = os.path.join("D:\\file\\{}.{}.tif.tif").format(a,b)
        new_file = os.path.join("D:\\file\\{}.{}.tif").format(a,b)
        os.rename(old_file, new_file)
        b += 1
        if b > 7:
            a += 1
            if a > 280:
                break
```

Comment: Check if the file exists before renaming it? `if os.path.isfile(old_file)`

Comment: do you only want to change one file, or do you want to swtich the numbers on all the files?

Comment: Side note: the way you're putting the full path in there you do not need `os.path.join()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
b += 1
if b > 7:
    a += 1
    # NOTE Missing b = 1
    b = 1
    if a > 280:
        break
```

### better implementation

```py
import os


# a filename generator
def create_filenames() -> str:
    """this creates filenames one file at a time"""
    for a in range(20, 280):
        for b in range(1, 7):
            yield f"D:\\file\\{a}.{b}.tif.tif"


# list of filenames to go through
old_filenames = [os.path.join(filename) for filename in create_filenames()]

_results = [os.rename(old_file, old_file.replace('.tif.tif', '.tif')) for old_file in old_filenames if os.path.isfile(old_file)]
# basically results contains nothing dont do anything with them


#to print the list of filenames do this
print(*old_filenames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the files you're trying to rename, you could use `for` loops instead.

Also, check if the file exists before you try to rename it.

```
import os

for prefix in range(20, 281):
    for suffix in range(1, 8):
        file = f"D:/file/{prefix}.{suffix}.tif.tif"
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            os.rename(file, file[:-4])
```